# How can I bind certain key on python tkinter bind_all func?

Tags: python, tkinter

c is the canvas, and I want to bind certain key( (ex)d ) to another function using c.bind_all()
IDK the event name that I should use..

```
c.bind_all('<KeyPress-D>', func)
```

dosen't work..

Comment: are you wanting to bind to lowercase "d" or uppercase "D"?

Comment: lowercase "d" , and actually it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

According to the [canonical tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm#M5) there are three ways to bind to a normal character (other than "<" or space):

- `c.bind_all("d", func)`
- `c.bind_all("<d>", func)`
- `c.bind_all("<KeyPress-d>", func)`